# Polish "l" with Lucida Sans font and biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to typeset the Polish "l" with biblatex. In the code below, the "l" is appearing as a square in the citation/bibliography. How can I get the Polish "l" to typeset?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alltt} % Paper size, default font size and one-sided paperR

\usepackage{nameref}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{etex}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=below}

\usepackage{placeins} % to control figure placement with \FloatBarrier

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lucida Sans}

% biblatex----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=99, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false,firstinits=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\usepackage{xpatch}

% No dot before number of articles
\xpatchbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
}{%
}{}{}

% Number of articles in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\bibliography{refs}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{WesolowskiFuller2012,
  title={Spatial variation and temporal shifts in habitat use by birds at the European scale},
  author={Weso{\l}owski, Tomasz},
  editor={Fuller, Robert J},
  booktitle={Birds and Habitat: Relationships in Changing Landscapes},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press},
  address={Cambridge},
  year={2012}
}

\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

    Some text \autocite{WesolowskiFuller2012}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Is you biblatex/biber up-to-date?

Comment: I've no idea to be honest. How can I check?

Comment: Check the log and the blg-file.

Comment: I found quite a lot of text containing `v2.5 biblatex` in the log file. What is latest version and how can I update?

Comment: The current version is biblatex v3.0, and biber 2.1. And I have no idea how you can update as you didn't mention your texsystem.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what my texsystem is either! How can I find out?

Comment: In the same way.

Comment: Various snippets from log file: `XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012) (format=xelatex 2012.6.30)`, `LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>`, `Babel <v3.8m>`

Comment: `TeX Live 2012` is rather old. Perhaps you should install 2015. But the more important information is that you are using xelatex. Why didn't you mention it? Add `\usepackage{fontspec}` to your file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: apologies but in my real .tex file, I already had `fontspec` loaded. I've updated code in question to match my real .tex file. The Polish "l" is appearing as a square - can you see what problem is?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer if I comment out `\setmainfont{Lucida Sans}` the Polish "l" works fine. But I need to use Lucida Sans.

Comment: Obviously your font doesn't have the glyph. Define some command that outputs an "l" and draws a stroke across it and then use this command instead.

Comment: I have `Lucida Sans OT`; is `Lucida Sans` an OpenType font?

Comment: If I change font to `\setmainfont{Lucida Sans}` I get this LaTeX error:  `Font EU1/LucidaSansOT(0)/m/n/10="Lucida Sans OT:" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.`