# Define a command to typeset a character

Tags: biblatex

If I run the code below, the Polish L in "Wesolowski" is not typesetting. To remedy this, I'm trying to define a command to typeset the Polish L. In the code below I've defined the command in this line:

```
\newcommand{\PolishL}{l\llap{\raise0.2em \hbox{\tiny\slash}\kern-0.05em}}
```

But this command is still not typesetting the Polish "L"

Alternatively, is there a way to typeset the Polish L without having to define a command?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alltt} % Paper size, default font size and one-sided paperR

\usepackage{nameref}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{etex}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=below}

\usepackage{placeins} % to control figure placement with \FloatBarrier

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lucida Sans}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\PolishL}{l\llap{\raise0.2em \hbox{\tiny\slash}\kern-0.05em}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% biblatex----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=99, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false,firstinits=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\usepackage{xpatch}

% No dot before number of articles
\xpatchbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
}{%
}{}{}

% Number of articles in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\bibliography{refs}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{WesolowskiFuller2012,
  title={Spatial variation and temporal shifts in habitat use by birds at the European scale},
  author={Weso{\PolishL}owski, Tomasz},
  editor={Fuller, Robert J},
  booktitle={Birds and Habitat: Relationships in Changing Landscapes},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press},
  address={Cambridge},
  year={2012}
}

\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

    Some text \autocite{WesolowskiFuller2012}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the `\l` doesn't work, it doesn't help to hide it in another command. You must do something like `\newcommand{\PolishL}{l\llap{\raise0.2em \hbox{\tiny\slash}\kern-0.05em}}` (but with something better than `tiny\slash` for the rule).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've updated my code to include your command but this is still not typesetting the Polish L

Comment: Does `\l` or `ł` work without `\setmainfont{Lucida Sans}`? Which version of `biber` you are using? Are you using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX?

Comment: Works fine (if one ignores that bad looking slash) for me with xelatex and a current biblatex/biber.

Comment: I don't have the font, did anybody check if it contains the glyph? There was a related question before: [Polish "l" with Lucida Sans font and biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251938)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your problem might simply be the real name of `the open type`/`truetype` `Lucida Sans`font. On my system, it is `Lucida Sans Unicode` and it compiles fine.

Note: I commented `\addbiresource{refs.bib}`  since I don't have it. Also you shouldn't write `\bibliography{refs}`– or don't use `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alltt} % Paper size, default font size and one-sided paperR

\usepackage{nameref}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{etex}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=below}

\usepackage{placeins} % to control figure placement with \FloatBarrier

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lucida Sans Unicode}

% biblatex----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=99, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false,firstinits=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\usepackage{xpatch}

% No dot before number of articles
\xpatchbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
}{%
}{}{}

% Number of articles in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

%\addbibresource{refs.bib}
%\bibliography{refs}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{WesolowskiFuller2012,
  title={Spatial variation and temporal shifts in habitat use by birds at the European scale},
  author={Wesołowski, Tomasz},
  editor={Fuller, Robert J},
  booktitle={Birds and Habitat: Relationships in Changing Landscapes},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press},
  address={Cambridge},
  year={2012}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

    Some text \autocite{WesolowskiFuller2012}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]